# How do I generate Touch Events in Windows 7 with C#?

Tags: c#, windows-7

In the past I've used the p/invoke SendInput function to generate keyboard and mouse events but apparently touch is a whole new beast. Is there any way in Windows 7 that I can generate a touch event with C#?

Comment: why would you want to do this? Send data to another app?

Comment: I want to create my own way of interacting with the desktop remotely (without keyboard/mouse) and thought touch would be an interesting way to go.